# How to avoid certain HTML tags in tinymce?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I don't show a fiddle because it doesn't even seem to work in the tinymce documentation. Please watch [the demo here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/valid-elements/#), in JS it says `invalid_elements: 'strong, b, em, i',` however you can clearly make the text bold.

Is there something I'm missing? Why is it not working?

EDIT: you can test this minimal playable code also by pasting it [here](https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  invalid_elements: 'strong,b,em,i',
  valid_elements: 'p',
});
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Aren't you writing that JS code?

Comment: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@valid_elements/

Comment: Use * [ * ] to include all elements and all attributes.

Comment: Avoiding a `<strong>`  tag does avoid a `style="font-weight: bold;"`. There are many ways to tweek the CSS...

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I am familiar with the rules. What better reproducible example than the documentation demo? Either way, right away I put my tinymce initializer. By the way, according to that line of code both <b> and <strong> should be restricted

Comment: @Robert that link is from old documentation. What I want is not to allow all classes and attributes. I want to prohibit the use of certain tags, for example bold or strong.

Comment: I see know... But from [documentation](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@invalid_elements/) : *Elements in this list will be removed when TinyMCE executes a cleanup.*... mmph.. Not an answer, I am mystified like you.

Comment: Have a look at this, which I think enables you to define the formatting buttons in the default bar: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/Configuration3x/Configuration3x@theme_advanced_buttons_1_n/

Comment: invalid_elements - *This option doesn't accept attributes in the list, only elements* - So only options is whitelist what is allowed so you can write: valid_elements: 'p[class, id]',

Comment: Take a look how deffine allowed attibutes on elements [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements)

Comment: check what editor changes when text is bold. maybe you should block some styles [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_styles)

Comment: It seems that it is as you say @Louys, that it only filters those tags when the content is saved, which seems to me to be a poor functionality from tinymce. Thanks

Comment: @Robert, I want to avoid tags as well, not just styles.

Comment: if you want avoid tags then use mark down editor....